# I have some problem with this excel formula =IF(A2:J2=O2,"Yes","No")

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am testing this if condition to whether O2 cell is matching with an element in A2:J2.
But the formula is displaying in the other 10 cells.
How can I get rid of this issue and execute the formula in only one cell?

Comment: Try: `=if(or(o2=a2:j2),"Yes","No"). Depending on your version,  may need to confirm with `ctrl+shift+enter`. If you are entering this into a Table, the formula will get copied down the column.

Comment: If you want the result in one cell then use `TEXTJOIN()` with if formula.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your criteria for the IF function: A2:J2=O2 is an array, which is the reason why it's spilling the values to the other cells. It's basically doing this: `A2=O2 B2=O2 C2=O2 D2=O2 and so on..`
   And it returns all of the result of these. Therefore, you will have an array of results.
2. Maybe you want to consider this formula: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(O2,A2:J2,0)),"Yes","No")`
   The match searches for O2 in A2:J2. If it finds the first match, it will return its position within the range. Otherwise, it will return an error. Therefore, we use ISNUMBER to check if the result of the match is a number. If it's a number, the ISNUMBER will return true. Otherwise, false. Then we'll use IF to capture the result of the ISNUMBER to return Yes if TRUE and No if FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this issue:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:J2,O2)>0,"Yes","No")
```

this formula will count the content of cell O2 within A2:J2 and if available, it will return a number greater than 0.